# Speech discrimination from animal sound

Tags: cross-correlation, speech-recognition, autocorrelation, speech, speech-processing

i am looking for discrimination of speech from animal sound if you take a 150ms frame of speech and bird as shown below, what feature can i extract from them so that i can effectively state the difference

[image: 1st is speech 2nd is animal(bird)]

zero crossings ?
cross correlation of successive frames seems high in bird sound ? isn't it 
any other feature from your side ?

[image]

one more example in above fig black-speeches,yellow siren,red bird,safron heavy wind the spikes are foot steps

above figure shows the difference in formant positions on spectrogram
in bird sounds the formants are differently spaced and less formants

will anything could be extracted from this analysis

the reason is i am looking for unsupervised(with out any training or SVM) speech discrimination form animal sounds because both are voice but computers cant classify the difference unless they are trained by any nueral network which need huge memroy and training database

Comment: Can you explain what you will be expecting as input to your system and what it should produce as output. e.g. the input is a signal containing bird sound and human speech, the ouput is a record of all the time periods containing human speech.

Comment: essentially i am trying to implement a speech only detector and encode speech only frames this is intended for a forest kind of environment

Comment: @Shyam You're going to have a problem without any given training data. You haven't though, provided any details of the types of birds, nor, have you provided any details to the frequency ranges that these birds are emitting at. This would probably be a good idea, especially since these could potentially be good characteristics for building a recogniser.

Answer (score 1):

The essence of your problem is one of [Voice Activity Detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_activity_detection) (VAD). This is a well researched topic and you should investigate the available algorithms - there are many papers available online, [here for example](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~dlsun/papers/voice_activity_detection_full.pdf)

You should apply a VAD algorithm to the signal and replace non-speech areas with silence, you can then look at the specific edge cases which are concerning you, such as animal sounds have being incorrectly considered speech.

For the case of animal sounds you may want to investigate Formant Detection (for example [this paper](http://www.ai.rug.nl/~tjeerd/publications/valkenier09.pdf)) since as you pointed out there is a distinction between them. You may also want to consider developing a heuristic based on your own empirical data about the differences. You can take many signal features such as the fundamental frequency, the signal power/amplitude, peakedness etc... and weight these appropriately to give you a confidence rating about the likelyhood of it being animal rather than human speech. This is a fuzzy approach, you would need to iterate a lot on the weightings and metrics.

Comment: Note that I intentionally did not mention cross/auto correlation as I don't think it would give you good results in this situation

Comment: i have checked for formants only few birds make a constant fundamental frequency for a period of time and its only valid for few birds and some other birds exhibit some other properties which can be valid human properties ...if that is so there is no limit for such type of sounds the first paper you shown needs training which is only environment and speech dependent 
if i train a system with English it cannot identify Japanese then ? how can we overcome such type of situations
most implementations train the system with huge amount of speeches doesn't  it seem hectic ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid some degree of training and/or empirical tweaking - there is a reason that the most effective VAD approaches have a training step.

Comment: will there be universal speech detectors?
i mean can any trained system detect any kind or any language of human speech ?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple yes or no answer to that question. I imagine there are some VAD approaches which can detect all forms of human speech _to some level of accuracy_. If that level of accuracy is sufficient for your purposes then the answer is yes, but there isn't much way of telling without trying and tweaking - so we are back to issues of domain and empiricism.

Comment: Considering the degree to which parrots can mimic humans, I don't think you can ever differentiate all birds from all humans.